# Unable to override Fulltext\Collection in module etc/di.xml

Tags: magento2, module, custom, model

**Preconditions**

1. Magento 2.1.1
2. Using Ubuntu/trusty64 vagrant-box, php7, apache

**Steps to reproduce**

1. Add a new custom module
2. Update etc/di.xml in your custom module

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">   
      <preference for="Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection" type="Sanimarkt\App\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection" /> 
   </config>
   ```
3. Add new Collection.php file and override `_renderFiltersBefore()` method

   ```
   namespace Sanimarkt\App\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext;
   class Collection extends \Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection
   {
     protected function _renderFiltersBefore()
     {
       die('stopping here')
     }
   }
   ```
4. clear cache
5. Make a search request

**Expected result**

1. The search request should stop and show 'stopping here' on the screen

**Actual result**

1. Nothing happens the custom class

`Sanimarkt\App\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection.php` is not executed.

Comment: Please follow http://webkul.com/blog/overriding-rewriting-classes-magento2/

Comment: that's exactly what I am doing with no success.

Answer (score 2):

It's opened on official repo - https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7734

Looks like it's not a bug for core team understanding. Yes, maybe, it's not a good idea, to override Fulltext\Collection, but I think it limitation, because you can not extend this class:

- Plugins don't work because of a protected method
- Events don't work, because no event is fired
- Override doesn't work, because of virtual types
- Override of virtual type doesn't work, because it breaks the search result

Answer (score 0):

After that, you have to recompile.

```
bin/magento setup:upgarde

bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Then check